# License error using Benchmark.NET + DevArt dotConnect for PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, .net, dotconnect, benchmarkdotnet

I'm working on an application consisting of several projects and using EntityFramework with dotConnect to run against PostgreSQL. I also have a license for dotConnect which successfully works in the main application.

In parallel, I'm crafting a console application(a different solution) using Benchmark.Net to measure the performance of the logic of one of the projects. But every time I run the benchmark  I'm getting the error below:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlException: Assembly that contains embedded dotConnect for PostgreSQL license cannot be used with this application: 0f238e83-669a-46b8-876f-40331880ee79.exe.exe.

Following [this instruction](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/PostgreSql/docs/), I have already generated `licenses.licx` through Visual Studio and `<exe file>.licenses` via `lc.exe`. But it is still producing the same error.

I'm suspecting that the fact that Benchmark.NET generates its own exe to run the benchmark causing this error but I'm not 100% sure. So I'm looking for a solution if anybody has one?

Thank you

Comment: @dymanoid, how to do this? Could you, please, point me to the documentation of Benchmark.NET or any sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure it's a good idea to create a benchmark for code that does database calls etc. You're benchmarking not the *code* then, but your whole *system* instead: the file system, the database drivers, possible interop stuff, and so on.

This is not the idea of BenchmarkDotNet. It's actually created for benchmarking of relatively small CPU-bound tasks to find bottlenecks and perform optimizations based on measurements.

However, if you still want to do that, a solution might be to run the benchmark in-process of the console app you've created, without producing special benchmarking assemblies.

To do so, use the [`[InProcess]`](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/samples/IntroInProcess.html) attribute. Just apply it to your benchmark class instead of usual job attributes:

```
[InProcess]
public class TypeWithBenchmarks
{
    [Benchmark]
    public void BenchmarkedMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you a lot. As for the benchmark itself, well, despite the fact that I agree that BenchmarkDotNet is designed for micro-benchmarking, I have to highlight that the logic I'm testing is quite lightweight and I have already found a performance problem in it using BenchmarkDotNet. So I think so far it meets all my needs

Comment: After applying the fix I got `Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: List of measurements contains no elements`. It is a BDN bug which seems to be fixed in 0.11.2.849. To install this nightly build, follow the instructions: https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/guides/nuget.html#nightly